# Using entity query build to apply conditions on all revisions

Tags: 7, entities, database

Best practice deems that you should use `EntityFieldQuery` for queries that somehow involve fields and entities.

An example of query to look for nodes with a timestamp value set in the future would be the following code.

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', REQUEST_TIME, '>')
  ->execute();
```

Is applying the conditions on all revisions, instead of only the active revision, possible?

A direct query on the database tables used to store the field revision values could eventually stop to work when Drupal changes some implementation details, such as the name of the used database tables, or the data stored in those database tables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `EntityFieldQuery` has a method, [`EntityFieldQuery::age()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3Aage/7.x), which is used to limit the revisions of the returned entities. It can be set to:

- [`FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/constant/FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT/7.x) (default)
  It queries the most recent revisions for all entities.
- [`FIELD_LOAD_REVISION`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/constant/FIELD_LOAD_REVISION/7.x)
  It queries all the revisions.

Support for this value ultimately depends on the query callback. The default query callback, [`field_sql_storage_field_storage_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!field_sql_storage!field_sql_storage.module/function/field_sql_storage_field_storage_query/7.x), which is the [`hook_field_storage_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_storage_query/7.x) implementation done from the field storage module, uses it to query the appropriate revision tables.